# Get a hash representation from Redis::Objects

Tags: ruby, redis

I'm using Redis::Objects

https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects

I want to modify the class in a presenter before I convert the object to JSON, so I want to do is merge in a key, but not have to manage the accessors for the redis object class within the presenter.

```
class MyOb
  include Redis::Objects

  value :foo
  value :bar
end

myob = new MyOb
myob.foo = "foo"
# I can do
myob.to_json #=> valid string with foo and bar keys
# what i want
myob.to_h #=> {foo: "foo", bar: nil}
# so i can
myob.to_h.merge(baz: "baz"}.to_json
```

I have not found anything that gives me a like representation so if you know the magic api sauce i'd love to hear about it.
Thanks!

Comment: First to edit my answer: Instead of convert to an Hash and reconvert to json is not better to implement in `MyOB` a merge like method that works with json values? like `myob.merge(valid_json)` in last line of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack it inefficiently like this:

```ruby
class MyOb
  def to_h
    JSON.parse(self.to_json)
  end
end
```

**[Edit]** Or you could do this so you don't have to track the keys in multiple places:

```ruby
class MyOb
  def to_h
    Hash[MyOb.redis_objects.map { |k,_| [k, self.send(k)] }]
  end
end
```

Comment: That is definitely an option, but it seems wasteful to parse one way just to parse it back. seems like there must be someplace in the api where to_json is getting its information from. the second solution is doing exactly what i'd like to avoid, which is having to take care of worrying about declaring the keys in two places. Thanks though.

Comment: @JedSchneider: Does redis-objects provide a way for an extended object to list its Redis values (e.g. those declared as :foo, :bar, etc)?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, sort of part of the solution i'm seeking. thanks!

Comment: @JedSchneider: see my updated answer, I think it'll do the trick using the "redis_objects" accessor.

Comment: I dont see that redis_objects is an accessor on the base class, I think you'd have to be within a specific type of object, like a counter. on the irb console, my object has no such attribute or method.

Comment: giving you the benefit of the doubt on this one. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'json'

class MyOb
  include Redis::Objects

  value :foo
  value :bar

  def to_h
   JSON.parse(self.to_json)
  end
end
```